# Semaphores used for signaling in threads not working(concurrency issue)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, signals, semaphore

in this project I am trying to do some concurrency among threads using semaphores as signaling, however the concurrency is not working at all. I can only use acquire and release and no synchronized keyword methods allowed. I read countless webpages and it says that

// do something

acquire()

release()

//do something

Which I understand but in this program I am trying to test signals with a semaphore between threads, for example user requests deposit and teller should say deposit completed.However my signals(semaphores) are not working as I want to print in order for example

I need to deposit 
Deposit is complete

instead I get this

Customer0created

I need to deposit

I have withdrawn <---

Customer0joined from main

Teller0created

You wanna withdrawal? <---- (out of order)

Deposit is complete

Regardless how i reorder them or how much i read the semaphore signaling to comm threads is not working.

```
 [code]import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

 public class Threads {


 private static Semaphore depositTransaction = new Semaphore (1, true);
 private static Semaphore withdrawal = new Semaphore (1, true);

 public static void main(String[] args) 

   {
    final int customerThreads = 1;
    final int tellerThreads = 1;
    final int loanThreads = 1;

    Customer thr[] = new Customer[customerThreads]; //  
   Thread cThread[] = new Thread[customerThreads]; //         
    for (int i= 0; i < customerThreads; i++)
    {
        thr[i]= new Customer(i);
        cThread[i] = new Thread(thr [i]);
        cThread[i].start();

    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < customerThreads; i++ )
    {
        try {
            cThread[i].join();
            System.out.println("Customer"+i + "joined from main");

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }

    Teller thr1[] = new Teller[tellerThreads];
    Thread tThread[] = new Thread[tellerThreads];
    for (int b = 0; b< tellerThreads; b++)
    {
        thr1[b] = new Teller(B)/>;
        tThread[b]= new Thread(thr1 [b]);
        tThread[b].start();
    }              
}   

static class Customer implements Runnable
 {
private int customerNumber = 0;
private int balance = 0;

Customer(int cn)
{
   this.customerNumber = cn;
   balance = 1000;
   System.out.println("Customer"+ customerNumber + "created");
}

public void run()
{

    try
    {

     System.out.println("I need to deposit");
    depositTransaction.acquire();// signal

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   withdrawal.release();
   System.out.println("I have withdrawn");
}       
}

static class Teller implements Runnable 
{
private int tellerNumber = 0;

Teller(int tn)
{
    this.tellerNumber = tn;
    System.out.println("Teller"+ tellerNumber +"created");
}

public void run()
{
    try 
    {

    System.out.println("You wanna withdrawal?"); 
    withdrawal.acquire();

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    }
    depositTransaction.release();
    System.out.println("Deposit is complete");
}

} 

}[/code]
```

Comment: You will get a better response if you rework the question to a minimal test case that clearly focuses on a specific question about semaphores.  As it is you have included your entire program, and not made it clear a) what should happen and b) what is happening.

Comment: I just edited it and reduced it down and did explain where my problem was and why it was wrong.

Comment: better, thank you.  However I am still unclear on your goal.  Are you for the teller thread to wait for a customer to make a deposit request, and then and only then for the teller thread to action?

Comment: if yes, then you have both semaphores set to accept the first request.  Teller would start without having any customer at all.  Remember that a semaphore decrements on acquire (blocking if the semaphore is at zero) and increments on release.

Comment: Yes ,that is my goal right now which I am doing with print line statements then I will add actions, customer requests and teller waits for it. I followed the other answer from eric but my threads hang. However in the future there will be actions that will make the customer thread wait for the teller but for now you are correct.

Comment: in that case, you are close.  Your problem is that you are letting both threads start too early.  Start the semaphores at zero, and only release the semaphore for the thread that you want to wake up.  I will follow with a close example, but not one so close that you can submit it for your homework ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program that uses a semaphore to play ping pong.  It is very similar to what you need for your goal.  This program has one thread that will print PING, and the other prints PONG.  It uses a semaphore to ensure that PING is printed first, then PONG, then PING and so on.

Notice how this program uses two semaphores, and that it starts both semaphores at zero.  This means that when the threads call acquire() on it, they will block.  You have been using the value of one, which means that neither thread would block and that both would rush ahead.

Now that all threads have blocked, we need to get one of them to start.  We send a 'release()' signal to the semaphore that the thread that we want to start up on.  That will increment the semaphore by one, and the thread blocked in acquire() will wake up and decrement it again before proceeding with its all important job of printing PING or PONG.

Remember the following about semaphores:

- A semaphore contains an integer value (called a permit count)
- acquire() will block until the integer value is greater than zero; when greater than zero the count will be decremented by one before exiting
- release() never blocks.  It only ever increments the integer value by one, and as a side effect wakes up any method that were blocked in a call to acquire().

Thus for a game of ping pong to work:  (ascii art below scrolls to the right)

```
            
   s1=0             -- release() -->  s1=1                                          s1=0
   s2=0                               s2=0                                          s2=1
   thread1=blocked                    thread1 runs      -- calls s2.release() -->   thread1 blocked
   thread2=blocked                    thread2=blocked                               thread2 runs
```

Notice how the values of s1 and s2 oscilate between 0 and 1, but we do not allow them both to have the value of 1 at the same time.  If they were ever to both equal 1, then both thread1 and thread2 would be able to run at the same time.  Which would be known as a race condition, as the order of their execution would be unpredictable.

```
public class PingPong {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        final Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(0);
        final Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore(0);

        final AtomicInteger countDown = new AtomicInteger( 10 );
        Thread threadA = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("threadA started");
                    while (countDown.get() > 0) {
                        s1.acquire();

                        System.out.println( "PING" );

                        s2.release();

                        countDown.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("threadA finished");
            }
        };

        Thread threadB = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("threadB started");
                    while (countDown.get() > 0) {
                        s2.acquire();

                        System.out.println( "PONG" );

                        s1.release();

                        countDown.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("threadb finished");
            }
        };

        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();


        s1.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example which I will study but why is only threadA joined and not B?

Comment: @user3034262 no particular reason;  I just wanted the main thread to block.  The truth is, because I have used non-daemon threads you could remove the join() and the program will behave in exactly the same way.

Comment: I removed the join() so as to reduce any noise in the example.  The core of the example is how the semaphore is being used, and how the threads will block until the main() method calls s1.release() at the end.  That is the trigger point for waking the first thread, which will then wake the second thread before going to sleep itself.  It will then wake up again once the second thread wakes it up, and so it repeats.

Comment: Say for some reason you then want to reverse the order as well, make thread A pong and thread B ping ( in addition to the current stuff ) but of course as a different action. So you have 2 semaphores, one makes it message ping-pong and the other pong-ping with same 2 threads, What could you do then? Apart from adding a new semaphore and reversing the order of release and acquire to make the other one wait signal, would you have to restart the threads? I have to do something similar...

Comment: To reverse the order of the example that I have given, so it becomes PONG then PING simply replace the very last `s1.release();` (after both of the threads) with `s2.release();`.

Comment: I mean have both the reverse order and the normal order. 2 of them , so 2 different semaphores between the 2 threads doing different things.Maybe you did understand me and I am just sleep deprived sorry xD. Thank you for all your help! If I had a 3rd thread that communicates differently with other 2 threads and such , the same process is still followed correct? You have cleared up a lot of questions so far!

Comment: @user3034262 rather than hacking that in to the example, I would take a step back and redesign the algorithm but using the same principles used above.  I do not want to risk giving you too much, as this is a homework assignment that you need to solve.  However if you think of semaphore as a stop/go flag then you may make more progress.  That is, all threads block on STOP as the starting state.  Then when you want a thread to do something, you change its owning semaphore to a state of GO.  This implies one semaphore per thread.

Comment: So it is not possible to have multiple semaphores per threads?I know it increases deadlock possibilities but I may need it for my project , say a lot of different actions that require threads to switch roles. For example 6 critical sections(using semaphores) and 3 different threads that may run3 times each. Thank you for your help so far and yeah the goal here is for me learn the methods and atleast know I am in the right direction, and have been helped greatly here.

Comment: @user3034262 you are welcome.  I would not go as far as saying that you cannot do it with multiple semaphores per thread, although a thread can only block on one semaphore at a time.  What I would say, is that I would strongly recommend against it.  From experience, I have found that smart/determined people can make almost anything work.. that does not mean that they should.  This is often what causes programmers to have so many passionate arguments :)

Comment: I suspect that you are feeling that you need to block against multiple semaphores per thread because that has been the first workable solution that came to mind.  We all tend to jump at our first ideas.  Creating a single semaphore per thread, which that thread and that thread alone blocks on makes for a fairly simple rule.  And simple is good, especially when concurrency is involved.  After all, concurrency bugs are HARD to track down.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using semaphores correctly for what you want to do. As I get it, you want to start the customer thread, then block until the teller threads finishes then finish the customer thread.

Right now your semaphore do close to nothing. They will prevent multiple customer threads from running at the same time, but within your acquire / release block, nothing happens.

If you want to synchronize between customer and teller, both classes need to use the same Semaphore

What I would suggest is this :

```
remove the join operation for now
create the depositTransaction semaphore with count 0, so the first acquire will block.
Start a customer thread
The thread will block waiting for a deposit
Start a teller thread
make the deposit and release the depositTransaction semaphore
the customer thread will unblock
you can now join both threads
```

Edit :

I don't think that your idea of adding tons of semaphore for every action is a good idea. You will end up with complex locking and deadlocks all over the place. What I would suggest is to limit the number of semaphore and implement messages between the threads. The semaphore will tell the other one (Client tells Teller and vice-versa) to check the messages after pushing one.

```
Start customer thread
push message that customer is waiting
signal for new customer request
wait for teller signal
Start teller thread
acquire sem for new customer request
check message
do stuff
signal customer that stuff is done
```

messages will then be "withdrawal customer 0" or any other action you want to implement

Comment: I am going to have multiple semaphores with other operations(some signaling from teller for example and waiting in customer/release) so I don't see how I can do that for everything like withdrawal, receipt etc where I will have more signals.I will have 5 customers when I expand this program. Also, how do you join 2 different threads? I appreciate your help! I thought i needed permits(the count in semaphores).

Comment: I mean join them separately, but not before the end of the main

Comment: When I do this , my threads hang again, when I use 0 for count.The program just waits forever.This was an issue I had earlier the the count increment for permissions stopped that error.

Comment: did  you remove the join at the start? If you try to join right away, then your thread will die and the teller won't be able to interact with the customer since they are started later on

Comment: Yeah I started both , customer first, then teller, and then at the end joined customer, then joined teller thread. This was all done in main if you run my code you will see the threads just hang and makes no sense to me , the syntax is all correct. Maybe because I need to sleep the threads in their run methods?

Comment: Be aware that nothing blocks in your scenario. first .acquire() is ok since the Semaphore count is 1, it gets to 0 and continues. Then you release the other Sem. Fine, the count is now 2. Then your Teller starts, it actions the withdrawal sem, the count is 1. Finally it releases the other sem, its count is back to 1

Comment: Yeah I do that because I wanted to test another case where I make the teller request and the customer wait. So for every semaphore I have to start and join the threads? I don't know how to make this work with 2 semaphores and I will have much more soon.

Comment: Yeah my pseudocode looks similar to that but the code is the issue. Some simple example code with proper syntax or so would really help me out , I understand the concept but I am just frustrated that other examples won't work for me when I code it. I appreciate all your help! I can't use synchronize functions/keywords as instructed which makes this harder.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to look at one of the standard examples and rework your code. Semaphore is very easy to use and all we need to do is acquire the lock when a thread accesses the shared resource and release the lock when it it is done.

There is nice example with a producer and a consumer thread protecting a shared resource here.
[Semaphore Example with a Producer and Consumer thread](https://www.stackstalk.com/2014/09/java-semaphore.html)